# How to receive an email over smtpd and sockets

Tags: python, sockets, smtp

I have some code trying to receive an email sent from a server on a client. The email is definitively sent from the server to the client, and a SMTP server on the client should be able to receive this email. Here is my test implementation:

```
# define the SMTP server (with the real IP adress of the client of course)
server = smtpd.PureProxy(('XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX', 25), None)        
inputs = [server]
outputs = []
message_queues = {}
readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)

# Only one socket in the list returned (there is exactly one)
socket = readable[0]

# Accept the connection or get it or whatever
connection, client_address = socket.accept()

# get the data
data = connection.recv(1024)
print data
```

After a considerably long time some data is received, which in no way resembles the content of the email. It is always

```
EHLO YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY
```

with the YYY the address of the server. I am no expert in SMTP and sockets, but what am I doing wrong to correctly receive the emai and its contents?

Thanks
  Alex

Comment: Given the numerous confusions present in the code and your description of it, this question cannot be answered in its present form. That two people have pointed out that you don't seem to understand the difference between a smtp client and server, either you need to improve your understanding or express your problem better.

Answer (score 1):

That is the proper start of the ESMTP protocol dialog. Your program needs to understand and handle at least the basic SMTP verbs; see [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321).

Comment: As I said the SERVER site is absolutely, perfect working!!!! I want to receive an email on the client, which has been successfully sent from the server to the client.

Comment: Your notion of what is "server" and "client" deviates from the normal usage. Anyway, updated the answer.

Comment: Maybe anyone knows an example script that uses python to make a proper communication between the server and the client, in order to receive the email, without the usage of asyncore? I havw googled for hours but no example came up.

Answer (score 1):

The `EHLO` is part of the [SMTP protocol exchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol#SMTP_transport_example) and it represents the client sending its greeting to your server which doesn't respond properly (because it doesn't respond at all). When the client gets tired of waiting for "a considerably long time" the session times out and your server shows what it received.

You seem to be confused as to which process is the server. The smtpd module creates servers or Mail Transport Agents, not clients. As noted in the [smtpd documentation for SMTPServer](http://docs.python.org/library/smtpd.html):

> Create a new SMTPServer object, which binds to local address
>   localaddr. It will treat remoteaddr as an upstream SMTP relayer. It
>   inherits from asyncore.dispatcher, and so will insert itself into
>   asyncore‘s event loop on instantiation.

You also seem to have the sense of `localaddr` and `remoteaddr` confused. The localaddr is not (as your comment claims) the address of the client, but where that server should accept connections from. You might want to try in place of your code:

```
server = smtpd.DebuggingServer(('localhost', 2525), None)
asyncore.loop()
```

Which can be tested with client code (in a separate process) of:

```
client smtplib.SMTP('localhost', 2525)
client.sendmail('from', 'to', 'body')
```

Finally, having a PureProxy with a remoteaddr of None, it if works at all, would proxy mail into nowhere which is probably not what you want in a proxy.

Comment: Hi, 
the setup with asyncore is the original setup to receive an email, which does not work in the first place!! Therefore I started to implement the socket code in order to see what is going wrong or to have an alternative way of implementing a reception of an email.

So if anyone can answer my original question, how exactly to implement the reception of the email with sockets WITHOUT any asyncore.

Many thanks
  Alex

Comment: To write a Mail Transfer Agent without asyncore will require you to re-invent the smtpd module which will require you to know the SMTP protocol which is quite complicated. The problem is not with asyncore, it is with your understanding.

Comment: It could well be my understanding, but also the system's understanding. The mail-sending server get the following error back: "502 Error: command "EHLO" not implemented". Does it mean I need to install EHLO on my ubuntu box?